# How to pivot this

Tags: sql, t-sql, pivot

```
BA21 YEAR   109 10  119 EBC
BA21 YEAR   9   0   9   FP
BA21 YEAR   3   0   3   BC
```

My data is like this  and I need to convert this to

```
BA21 YEAR 109 10 119 EBC 9 0 9 FP 3 0 3 BC
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

THis does not seem like [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx)ing, it more seems like a self join.

Something like

```
SELECT t1.*,t2.column1,t2.column2,...,t3.column1,t3.column2,...
FROM Table1 t1 INNER JOIN
Table2 t2 ON t1.PrimaryKey = t2.PrimaryKey INNER JOIN
Table3 t3 ON t1.PrimaryKey = t3.PrimaryKey
```

where you are selecting only the columns from Table2 and Table3 that you need.

Also, this can be changed to LEFT joins if required. Have a look at [Introduction to JOINs – Basic of JOINs](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/13/sql-server-introduction-to-joins-basic-of-joins/) for JOIN explenations.

Comment: Then you are facing using dynamic queries. PIVOTS are used for aggregating data.